# Building up an array/string using exported resources

Tags: puppet

I am in process of writing manifests to configure NXLog in our environment.
The idea is to call 'modules' similar to collectd on the clients, for example:
`nxlog::plugins::syslog` and/or `nxlog::plugins::nginx` etc etc

The step that I am getting stuck in, is building up the route at the end of the config file, the last line would have to contain `syslog, nginx` as a string value.

Initially I thought of using something such as $input += [$input], and setting the value of $input in each manifest. Then join the array with commas to create a string, but further reading of forums on this hinted strongly that this does not work.

The I thought of using an inline template `<%= input.flatten.join(',') %>` , but it seems someone else already tried that in a older post without success.

Is there a way to dynamically build up a string value from similar variables in exported resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if anyone else runs into this - here is how I fixed it, caveat, have to run PuppetDB for this...

```
  $q_all = (puppetdb_query("
    inventory[certname] {
      facts.app = 'graylog' and environment = '${::environment}'
    }"))

  $members_all = join(sort($q_all.map |$index, $c_name| { "${$c_name['certname']}:9300" }),',')
```

This will create a comma separated string of the array.
I had to include the sort else Puppet returns the string based on last check-in of the guests, the sort removes the possibility of this affecting a change.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to dynamically build up a string value from similar variables in exported resources?

I am not aware of any such way, and overall, extracting property values from declared resources is poor form.  Prior to Puppet 4, it wasn't possible at all, regardless of whether the resources involved were concrete, virtual, or exported.

Instead, you could consider producing the config you want as the effect of collecting and *applying* the exported resources, which presumably would require using a different resource type than you now do.  For example, you might manage the target file via the `Concat` module, and let the exported resources be instances of `Concat::Fragment` containing actual pieces of the needed target content.  This is a bit easier in cases where the target configuration can reasonably be split among several files, such that you can use `File`s for the type of your exported resources, but one way or another it can work for you.

Comment: Thanks John, so there is no way to build this up? My plan B was to specify all the 'modules' as an array and then to split that up and build logic into the manifest to build up the fragments. Using line items just looked cleaner.

Comment: @Werner, exported resources are not a general-purpose data sharing mechanism.  They are a mechanism to declare resources that are specifically associated with one node, such that they can be applied to other nodes.